# Decode transaction output

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, external-function

I have an external function that modifies the state and returns a value:

```
 function test(string memory testValue) external returns (string memory) {
        state = string.concat("test",testValue);
        return state;
  }
```

Running the SC with Remix I can see the decoded value:

```
decoded output: {
  "0": "string: testtest"
}
```

But I don't know how to get the same with the library ethersJS:

```
 const tx = await deployedSC.test("test");
 console.log(tx)
```